# What are the requirements for getting the Summerset Shadows quest for the Windhelm Fence?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got a quest called Summerset Shadows which gives me a fence in Windhelm (Niranye). My boyfriend is trying to get this quest too since Windhelm market has all the crafting tools and is very convenient, but he can't get Tonilia in the thieves guild to give him the quest.

We're both guild masters of the theives guild. I thought it might be # of quests done for the thieves guild (I had 17 at the time), but he has gotten the same amount done and still no quest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windhelm, Markarth, Solitude and Whiterun all have "influence" quests that each become available once you've done 5 of the randomly-generated jobs from Vex and Delvin in that city. Since jobs in Riften or cities you've already completed do not help your progress towards completing the influence quest, you can save before taking a job from Vex or Delvin and then reload until you get a city you haven't completed yet, if you feel so inclined.

Completing the influence quests unlocks fences in Markarth and Windhelm, but most importantly, each influence quest you complete increases the available gold pool of all fences in the world, up to 4000 once all quests are complete.

When you've completed all four influence quests, plus the main Thieves Guild storyline, you can become the guild master, receiving a significantly-upgraded suit of the guild armor you gained when joining.

Comment: Thank you, that would explain why he didn't have have the quest available even though he did the same number of Thieves Guild quests as me

Answer (score 3):

Trigger Thieves Guild quest - Summerset Shadows
Summerset Shadows given by Delvin Mallory of the Thieves Guild, who instructs to speak with Torsten Cruel-Sea of Windhelm. Quest is not added and speaking to Torsten presents no option to talk about the quest.

Reason: Linwe, leader of Summerset shadows was killed in an earlier "Kill the Bandit Leader" radiant quest, causing Summerset Shadows to bug and not start.

To fix:

1. Do not speak with Delvin first to start the quest. Preferably, leave one or two Thieves Guild Small Jobs quests unfinished by not speaking to Delvin or Vex to complete them yet. I left one done but incomplete by not speaking to Vex before following the steps below.
2. Go to Uttering Hills Cave - coc UtteringHillsCave01
3. Kill existing bandit chief there.
4. Replace with Linwe using code - player.placeatme 0007d679
5. Go back to The Ragged Flagon to complete all the necessary Small Jobs quests. I went back and spoke to Vex to complete my one and remaining Small Jobs quest.
6. Then speak with Delvin, and Summerset Shadows quest will be added.

This is the only solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

In order to be able to access the Summerset Shadows quest, you have to do miscellaneous jobs for Vex and Delvin in the Ragged Flagon. These jobs are:

For Vex: The Burglary Job, The Heist Job, The Shill Job, The Sweep Job.
For Delvin: The Numbers Job, The Fishing Job, The Bedlam Job.

Once you complete enough of these randomly generated jobs, you will be given a "special request" from Delvin. They don't show up as Thieves Guild quests in your General Stats, but as you complete the Special Requests, they will add to your Thieves Guild quest total.

Answer (score 0):

When none of the normal stuff works, which didn't for me (like `setstage tgtq04 200` and such), you can do this:

```
setstage tgleadership 0
```

It will not let you do the quest Summerset Shadows, but at least you can proceed in the TG questline.